# How to check if two arrays are completely different from each other in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently writing a PHP script where I need to check if an array contains an element which is in the second array too.

So I need a function which returns true only if the two arrays are completely different from each other.

I tried this one:

```
checkVariable = true;
arrayA = new array();
arrayB = new array();

foreach(arrayA as an) {
    if(in_array(an, arrayB)
        checkVariable = false;
    }
}

print_r(checkVariable);
```

But it does not work as expected.

The thing is that I have a two textboxes (black- and a whitelist of some IDs) which the user enters separated by "," (I will get an array by exploding the input values) and I need to check that there is no ID on the black- and on the whitelist at the same time.

So if an ID is present in both checkboxes at the same time the user should get an error-message and the process should be interrupted.

The problem with the script above is that the user is still able to save the same value in both textboxes sometimes and I don't know why.

Comment: Post sample arrays.

Comment: Edit the if to if(in_array(an, arrayB)){//Your code} and check the result .

Comment: Your could looks fine, assuming `arrayA` and `arrayB` have content in your real application. So the error must be somewhere else. You say the error occurs "sometimes", can you reproduce it? Can you var_dump the contents of the two arrays in this case? Maybe there are some subtle differences, like leading spaces in one array and not in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to check if there are any of the same values in arrays...

```
$checkVariable = true;
$white = "1,2,3,4,5";
$black = "6,7,8";
$white = explode(",", $white);
$black = explode(",", $black);

if ( count(array_intersect($white, $black)) > 0 )   {
    $checkVariable = false;
}

print_r($checkVariable);
```

Or simplify it to...

```
$white = "1,2,3,4,5";
$black = "1,6,7,8";
$white = explode(",", $white);
$black = explode(",", $black);

$checkVariable = count(array_intersect($white, $black)) > 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated code

```
checkVariable = true;
arrayA = new array();
arrayB = new array();

$result = array_diff(arrayA , arrayB );
if( count($result) > 0 ) // if there is a difference between array then it will retun the difference if there is no difference then it will not return any count.
{ 
  // both arrays are different.
}
```

moreover you can also check array different using below example

```
$arraysAreEqual = (arrayA  == arrayB); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
$arraysAreEqual = (arrayA  === arrayB); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work...

```
<?php
$checkVariable = true;
$arrayA = array("23", "34", "56");
$arrayB = array("23");

foreach($arrayA as $an) {
    if(in_array($an, $arrayB)) {
        $checkVariable = false;
    }
}

print_r($checkVariable);
//var_dump($checkVariable);
```

Returns false

Answer (score 0):

Try array_intersect() instead:

It return empty array if you have two different array otherwise return duplicate element.

`$a1=array('aaa','bbb');`

`$a2=array('ccc','ddd');`

`$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);`

`if(empty($result)){`

```
    `your array contain no duplicate element`
```

`}else{`

```
  `your array contain duplicate element`
```

`}`